# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).crmAutocomplete is not a function

Tags: civievent, drupal, civicontribute, civimember, custom-fields

CRM.$(function($) {
    $('#current_employer').crmAutocomplete({params:{contact_type:'Organization',group:18}});
});
i got error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).crmAutocomplete is not a function

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM are you using?  Which CMS (Drupal/WordPress/Joomla) ?

Answer (score 0):

The information you are giving us is way too little to be able to know what your problem is.
But I will make a wild guess....did you at some point use cj rather than $ so you get the right jQuery object? I would expect:

```
 cj('#current_employer').crmAutocomplete
```

Unless you specified somewhere that you are going to use $ for cj.